# Php inside the shortcode is getting commented

Tags: php, shortcode

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode('[learn_more caption="ancila"]
    <p>
        <?php echo get_post_meta($postid,principal_1,true)"; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </p>
    [/learn_more]');
?>
```

Php code inside this shortcode is not working..When this php code is given outside of shortcode,it is working..Please help me..

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 2):

You can not execute functions inside the `do_shortcode()` call like you are trying to. If you are just trying to wrap your post meta content with the shortcode, then you can do it like shown below.

```
$your_post_meta_variable_content = get_post_meta( $postid, principal_1, true ); 
echo do_shortcode( 
    '[learn_more caption="ancila"]' 
        . $your_post_meta_variable_content .
    '[/learn_more]'
);
```